# Past Tense of open graph action verb doesn't work in all timeline posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, action, facebook-opengraph

I'm in the process of developing a "wants to" action for an article.  Now that I am testing posts I am noticing that, in addition to the items and aggregations I define for this action, Facebook is also posting more generic versions of the action activity to a Timeline. These generic posts are titled " **wants to** and article", as seen here:

Problem Post: Generic Facebook Activity Post - http://bit.ly/wWSdTv

This obviously sounds a bit funky, but I can't redefine past tense form of "wants to" in order for other aggregations to work.  Here is the definition of the action within Facebook:

FB Action Definition - http://bit.ly/A0EEIx

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can work around this problem?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: wants to "purchase" an article?  wants to "try on" an article?  wants to "hide" an article?  What is the _actual_ verb?

Comment: examples of what we'd like are  <person> wants to <article title> where article title could be "Boil and Egg", "French Kiss", etc.  Alternatively, is there a way to prevent facebook from making activity type posts like the first link in the original post?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a great solution is possible here, so I'll give you an OK solution.

Action: **wants to do**
Object: **activity**

*Bobby wants to do an activity on MyApp: Boil an egg.*
*Bobby wants to do Boil an egg on MyApp.* (not great)

If you can "verbify" the activity title, that would help.

*Bobby wants to do Egg-boiling on MyApp.*

We don't really have any control over how Facebook displays the information, so try to consider all possibilities when creating objects and actions.

Maybe your "articles" could be several different types of objects depending on if it's something you "want to do" or something you "want to have", or as in your hipster example something you "want to wear".